# HOW to enable jenkins job to read user input variable?

Tags: jenkins

I have created jenkins job which create a new git branch and create some directory in the project using the following command:

```
mkdir -p myproject/newFolder
```

Now I would like to give to user to the possibility to give **newFolder** name from the job itself and not from the job configure. here is the use case:

1. user go to the jenkins job
2. user enter the name of **newFolder** let's say newFolder:**ThisIsMyNewFolder**
3. user starts the job
4. jenkins job runs and creates the new folder myproject/ThisIsMyNewFolder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a buildParameter and create parameterised build with `FOLDERNAME` as parameter

Then your batch will be like 
       `mkdir -p myproject/%FOLDERNAME%` 
and shell as 
         `mkdir -p myproject/$FOLDERNAME`